# Sidebar/menu that shows only selected submenu

Tags: html, angular

I would like to implement sidebar, that shows multiple items similar to accordion. However, I want it to display only selected submenu. For example - 
if I have 3 submenus, lets say People, Pets, Items, if I click on People it will display only People and button to go hierarchicaly back. It will not display Pets nor Items. Not even their header. Is there such a component?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just need to hide the submenus and show them on click. So, for example:

```
<div (click)="showSubmenu('people')">People</div>
<div *ngIf="showPeople" *ngFor="let person in people">
  <div>{{ person }}</div>
</div>
<div (click)="showSubmenu('pets')">Pets</div>
<div *ngIf="showPets" *ngFor="let pet in pets">
  <div>{{ pet }}</div>
</div>
....
```

Then in your component you need the showSubmenu function:

```
showPeople = false;
showPets = false;

showSubmenu(menu){
  if (menu === 'people') {
    this.showPeople = true;
    this.showPets = false;
    ....
  } else if (menu === 'pets') {
    ...
  ....
}
```

And so on for all the others. We have set the submenus names to false so they will not show by default, but when we click the title the function runs and shows the one we clicked, hiding the others.

Obviously this assumed that you have a pets and people array.